# How to start writing test framework for the web application using the selenium web driver and testNG?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Please provide some guidelines to start wiring the framework and provide suggestion about the architecture of the framework.

I am building my own framework so need help on the folder structure and the class structure guidelines

Comment: This is about TestNG , I am building my own framework so need help on the folder structure and the class structure guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Page object Model if you are building an automation framework. It's make your script maintainable and flexible

Refer it:-
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: welcome @HillHacker :)